# escaping Function keys for terminal applications

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xfce4-terminal

I'm trying to use F keys (<kbd>F1</kbd>,<kbd>F10</kbd>,<kbd>F11</kbd>) keys in terminal applications (e.g. `mutltitail` , `mc`) in terminal emulator (`xfce4-terminal`) but these keys are assigned to terminal emulator GUI (for help, menu & fullscreen)

how can I send <kbd>F1</kbd>,<kbd>F10</kbd>,<kbd>F11</kbd> to terminal applications in an terminal emulator ?

Comment: Could you split up the logic of what you are doing so that you could start another script to do just the part where you need to do this  with `nohup SOMESCRIPT.SH &` so that THAT script ran in the background and used xdotool to send the key simulations you want?

Comment: @LewRockwellFan: no; for example i'm using `mc` and it uses F10 for exiting `mc`;  or I'm using `multiterm` and i uses F1 for help; but I can't use them because when i press  F10 terminal emulator's File menu displays up

Comment: Just guessing, but have you looked at the documentation for these  apps? Usually there is a config file somewhere that will let you change keybindings to avoid exactly that kind of conflict.

Answer (score 2):

The F10 key can be disassociated with the terminal GUI by going to Preferences -> General, and then unchecking 'Enable the menu accelerator key'.

This answer has more information: [Ubuntu 18.04 Terminal F10 function key conflict with htop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035961/ubuntu-18-04-terminal-f10-function-key-conflict-with-htop/1035980)

I'm unsure about the F1 or F11 keys, but I suspect @LewRockwellFan may have the best solution by suggesting to look at the configuration for the applications you are trying to use.